# Encoding error when reading csv file containing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding

I used `df.to_csv()` to convert a dataframe to csv file. Under python 3 the [pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) states that it defaults to utf-8 encoding.

However when I run `pd.read_csv()` on the same file, I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 8: invalid start byte
```

But using `pd.read_csv()` with `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` works.

What is the issue here and how do I resolve it so I can write and load files with consistent encoding?

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Unable to, but I consistently get the problem for the dataframes I created using other data sets from the same source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a concrete example of pandas using some unknown(?) encoding when not explicitly using the `encoding` parameter with `pandas.to_csv`.

0x92 is ’ (looks like an apostrophe)

```py
import pandas
ERRORFILE = r'written_without_encoding_parameter.csv'
NO_ERRORFILE = r'written_WITH_encoding_parameter.csv'

df_dummy = pandas.DataFrame([u"Yo what's up", u"I like your sister’s friend"])

df_dummy.to_csv(ERRORFILE)
df_dummy.to_csv(NO_ERRORFILE, encoding="utf-8")

df_no_error_with_latin = pandas.read_csv(ERRORFILE, encoding="Latin-1")
df_no_error = pandas.read_csv(NO_ERRORFILE)
```

```py
df_error = pandas.read_csv(ERRORFILE)
>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte
```

So it looks like you have to explicitly use `encoding="utf-8"` with `to_csv` even though pandas docs say it is using this by default. Or use `encoding="Latin-1"` with `read_csv`.

Even more frustrating...

```
df_error_even_with_utf8 = pandas.read_csv(ERRORFILE, encoding="utf-8")
>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 18: invalid start byte
```

I am using Windows 7, Python 3.5, pandas 0.19.2.

Comment: Had the same issue, converted an excel df to a csv.  Later tried to read the csv and saw the 'utf-8' error - invalid start byte.  Using pd.read_csv() with encoding="ISO-8859-1" works but not sure why.  Maybe its a bug in Python 3.6?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to read the data using **encoding='unicode_escape'**.

Answer (score 2):

The original `.csv` you are trying to read is `encoded` in e.g. `ISO-8859-1`. That's why it's a `UnicodeDecodeError` - python / pandas is trying to `decode` the source using `utf-8` codec assuming per default the source is `unicode`.

Once you indicate the non-default source encoding, pandas will use the proper codec to match the source and decode into the format used internally.

See python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html) and more [here](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html). [Also very good.](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I did not try to read using `ISO-8859-1` as I encountered no Error while reading the original file in `utf-8`. Does this mean the error is possible even though I was able to load the original file and write it to my disk?

Comment: You are right that this is how it's supposed to work. If your file is `utf8` encoded as python 3 does indeed per default, you should be able to read it in without problems. This typically breaks when opening with another app in between, like excel.. Would need enough detail about file and process to be able to reproduce the error, sorry, so far can just interpret the error message.

Comment: Adding the parameters `encoding='utf-8'` to `df.to_csv()` solves the problem.